# Fancy arrow/Patch edge width

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code will produce a fancy arrow with matplotlib :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xy = [0.2,0.2]
xytext =[0.5,0.5]

plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
ax.annotate("", xy=xy, xytext=xytext,arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="<|-", edgecolor = 'k', facecolor = 'r', shrinkA = 0, shrinkB = 0))
```

The arrow is red, with black edges. How can I control the width of the black edges ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `linewidth` argument. Below is an example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xy = [0.2,0.2]
xytext =[0.5,0.5]

plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
ax.annotate("Text", xy=xy, xytext=xytext, arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="<|-, 
            head_width=2, head_length=2", edgecolor = 'k', facecolor = 'r',
            linewidth=4))
```

[image]